# Proof with Binomial Theorem

Tags: binomial-theorem

Quick question! if I have
$\varphi= (1 +\sqrt{5})/2$ and $\psi = (1 - \sqrt{5})/2$  and $n\ge0$ would be an int

How would I prove that in $(\varphi^n - \psi^n)/\sqrt{5}$ is an integer but only using Newtons binomial theorem?

Comment: Do you realize that $\;\psi\phi=-1\;$ ?

Comment: well I have to use binomal therom and the values are placed with the equation .

Comment: Expand $\varphi^n$ with the binomial theorem, just keeping a $2^n$ as the denominator.  Now do the same thing for $\psi^n$. Note that the terms are the same up to sign, when you subtract all the ones not involving $\sqrt{5}$ cancel each other out. See where you can go from there.